# jsFiddle - cant make simple script correct

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Please, tell me, why after clicking anchor, class "opened" is not attached to first child div inside #myheader element?

```
$('#showhide').click(function(){
    if ( $('#myheader>div').hasClass('opened') ) {
        $('#myheader>div').removeClass('opened');
        //$('#header>div.wrap>div.showme').removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        $('#myheared>div').addClass('opened');

    }
})​
```

JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberek/UrqnR/3/)

Comment: I don't mean to offend you, the -1 is just because this question wouldn't be of great use to others...

Comment: Questions emerging from typographic mistakes are too localised.

Comment: @MartinStettner It's better to just cast a close vote instead then :)

Comment: Damn, so stupid I am :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you made a typo:

```
$('#myheared>div').addClass('opened');
//       ^^^
```

Should be:

```
$('#myheader>div').addClass('opened');
```

It could be done in an easier way though, by using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('#showhide').click(function() {
    $('#myheader > div').toggleClass('opened');
});
```